# MongoDB and hierarchical content: update "breadcrumb" after hierarchy move

Tags: mongodb

I have documents in my DB modeled this way:

```
{
 "_id": ...
 "parentId": ...
 "content": "..."
}
```

A document can have as parent a document of the same collection (optional, there are "root" documents)

Think of it as a tree of documents.

```
{
 "_id": 1
 "parentId": undefined
 "content": "..."
}

{
 "_id": 2
 "parentId": 1 
 "content": "..."
}

{
 "_id": 3
 "parentId": 2
 "content": "..."
}
```

Then we have a hierarchy with a breadcrumb 1 > 2 > 3

For query purpose we have denormalized that breadcrumb in the documents, as it permits to query the breadcrumb to let's say, get all documents that are under 2 (returns 2 + 3)

```
{
 "_id": 1
 "parentId": undefined
 "content": "..."
 "breadcrumb" : [1]
}

{
 "_id": 2
 "parentId": 1 
 "content": "..."
 "breadcrumb" : [2,1]
}

{
 "_id": 3
 "parentId": 2
 "content": "..."
 "breadcrumb" : [3,2,1]
}
```

The "reverse" order of the breadcrumb is the correct order in our system. We may change it to the "normal" order if it helps but I'm trying to see it this is really required.

Now let's say we introduce a 4th and 5th document (which:

```
{
 "_id": 4
 "parentId": undefined
 "content": "..."
 "breadcrumb" : [4]
}
{
 "_id": 5
 "parentId": 4
 "content": "..."
 "breadcrumb" : [5,4]
}
```

And let's say we want to change the parent of document 2 and replace `parentId=1` by `parentId=5`.

How can we make a query so that all documents under document 2 have their breadcrumb updated?

I mean :

- Document 2 has [2,5,4] instead of [2,1]
- Document 3 has [3,2,5,4] instead of [3,2,1]

Getting the documents to update is easy: `{"breadcrumb": "2"}`

But I don't know how to build the update query as we should replace the end of the breadcrumb array with a new array.

I thought it would be possible to `$pull` 1 and then `$push` `$each: [4,5]` but it seems it's [not possible](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1050) to pull/push at the same time.
I'd rather do this in a single query.

I have potentially large document trees and the query should be able to update the breadcrumb of more than 10k documents.

Any idea?